# After how many years decline of Dharma will start steeply in Kaliyuga?

Tags: kali-yuga

About 5000 years have passed since KaliYuga has begun , and in my observation Santan Dharma has begun to decline steeply .
Is there anything mentioned in scriptures about when decline of Dharma will begun in KaliYuga ?

Comment: According to Devibhagavatapurana, real decline of Kaliyuga will begin after 10,000 years ( I.e another 5000 years from now).

Comment: @AnubrataBit Can you provide the verse number? Thanks.